# How to join second or third dimension array items without affecting first dimension

Tags: ruby, arrays, join, multidimensional-array, permutation

I am trying to create an array that shows every digit permutation of a given number input. With a given input `"123"`, the array should look like this:

```
["123", "132", "213", "231", "312", "321"]
```

I can get an array containing arrays of the separate digits:

```
a = []
"123".split('').each {|n| a.push(n) }
arraycombinations = a.permutation(a.length).to_a
# => [["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "3", "2"], ["2", "1", "3"], ["2", "3", "1"], ["3", "1", "2"], ["3", "2", "1"]]
```

but I cannot figure out how to join the second or third dimensions of `arraycombinations` while preserving the first dimension.

Each of these attempts failed:

```
arraycombinations.map {|x| print arraycombinations.join("") }
arraycombinations.map {|ar| ar.split(",") }
arraycombinations.each {|index| arraycombinations(index).join("") }
```

How can I isolate the `join` function to apply to only the second dimension within a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple really

```
"123".split("").permutation.to_a.map { |x| x.join }
```

Let me explain a bit:

`"123".split("")` gives you an array `["1","2","3"] 
permutation.to_a` gives you array of arrays `[["1","2","3"], ["2","1","3"] ... ]`
then you must join each of those arrays inside with `map { |x| x.join }` 
and you get the required end result.

Comment: Sweet. But OP already have an array of arrays that needs to be joined.

Comment: Oh I missed the point then :) But it seems to me that the last part answers the question.

Comment: Wow, your solution and approach to the problem is much more elegant than the direction I was going.

Just out of curiosity, what would be the steps to specify joining 3rd or higher dimensional arrays?  I knew that .flatten could affect dimensionality, but understanding how to target actions based on dimensions is where I got lost.

Comment: Well ugly solution off the top of my head would be to nest maps and joins ... so you would write array.map { |x| x.map { |y| y.join } } but maybe there is a prettier solution ...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have an array of arrays such as

```
a = [["1","2","3"],["1","3","2"],["2","1","3"],["2","3","1"], ["3","1","2"],["3","2","1"]]

a.map { |i| i.join}
#=>["123", "132", "213", "231", "312", "321"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
arraycombinations.map(&:join)
# => ["123", "132", "213", "231", "312", "321"]
```

Comment: Like the usage of &:join - didn't think of that :)